# javascript - generate a new random number

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that has a number between 1-3.

I need to randomly generate a new number between 1-3 but it must not be the same as the last one.

It happens in a loop hundreds of times.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: is it between 1-3, are we talking whole numbers? so options are 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: You realise that generating a number from 1-3 without repeating is a) not random and b) functionally equivalent to selecting one of two numbers, i.e. probability 0.5?

Comment: ok i understand b) but why a)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The efficiency of the loop depends on many things: Are you using this random in the loop only, should it be passed forward as an argument etc.

Comment: @Moshe because for it to be truly random, each number would have to be independent of the last. As you have the condition that there must be no repeats, the future numbers are affected by the past.

Comment: @Widor: things can be random even if they have dependencies on past values. What I think you're saying is that the numbers are not *independent*.

Comment: @lum Hmm, statisticians would disagree - all possible outcomes [1, 2, 3] would need to have an equal probability of being chosen for this to be true. With the conditions the OP describes, it's not just the next number that's affected - the number chosen on the n-th iteration is twice as likely to be chosen at iteration n+2 than either of the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**May the powers of modular arithmetic help you!!**

This function does what you want using the modulo operator:

```
/**
 * generate(1) will produce 2 or 3 with probablity .5
 * generate(2) will produce 1 or 3 with probablity .5
 * ... you get the idea.
 */
function generate(nb) {
    rnd = Math.round(Math.random())
    return 1 + (nb + rnd) % 3
}
```

if you want to avoid a function call, you can inline the code.

Comment: Nice, I did exactly the same inline :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jsFiddle that solves your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/AsMWG/

I've created an array containing 1,2,3 and first I select any number and swap it with the last element. Then I only pick elements from position 0 and 1, and swap them with last element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 1; // or 2 or 3
// this generates a new x out of [1,2,3] which is != x
x = (Math.floor(2*Math.random())+x) % 3 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly generate numbers with the random number generator built in to javascript. You need to use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

If you're [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)-ing into an array, you can always check if the previously inserted one is the same number, thus you regenerate the number. Here is an example:

```
var randomArr = [];
var count = 100;
var max = 3;
var min = 1;

while (randomArr.length < count) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    if (randomArr.length == 0) {
        // start condition
        randomArr.push(r); 
    } else if (randomArr[randomArr.length-1] !== r) { 
        // if the previous value is not the same 
        // then push that value into the array
        randomArr.push(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is tested and it does for what you are after.

```
var RandomNumber = {

    lastSelected: 0,

    generate: function() {

        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;

        if(random == this.lastSelected) {
            generateNumber();
        }
        else {
            this.lastSelected = random;
            return random;
        }
    }
}


RandomNumber.generate();
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's pretty good and not using array like all the others.

Comment: This did not work for me, it did not produce a new random number every time.

Answer (score 0):

As Widor commented generating such a number is equivalent to generating a number with probability 0.5. So you can try something like this (not tested):

```
var x; /* your starting number: 1,2 or 3 */
var y = Math.round(Math.random()); /* generates 0 or 1 */

var i = 0;
var res = i+1;
while (i < y) {
   res = i+1;
   i++;
   if (i+1 == x) i++;
}
```